# Determining the set of message destinations at runtime in BizTalk application

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I’m a complete newbie at BizTalk and I need to create a BizTalk 2006 application which broadcasts messages in a specific way. I’m not asking for a complete solution, but for advise and guidelines, which capabilities of BizTalk I should use.

There’s a message source, for simplicity, say, a directory where the user adds files to publish them. There are several subscribers, each having a directory to receive published files. The number of subscribers can vary in the course of exploitation of the program. There are also some rules which determine if a particular subscriber needs to receive a particular file, based on the filename. For example, each subscriber has a pattern or mask of filename which files they receives must match. Those rules (for example, patterns) can change in time as well.

I don’t know how to do this. Create a set of send ports at runtime, each for each destination? Is it possible? Use one port changing its binding? Would it work correctly with concurrent sendings? Are there other ways?

**EDIT**

I realized my question may be to obscure and general to prefer one answer over another to accept. So I just upvoted them.

Comment: I totally agree. SO is a great place to learn and help each other out. Accept which ever answer helped you the most. I'd suggest ChrisLoris - he's given you the most detail :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes to the destination are going to be frequent, you are right in seeking a more dynamic solution.  One nice solution is using dynamic send ports and the Business Rules Engine.  You create rule set for the messages you are receving.  This could be based on a destination property or customer ID in the message.  Using these facts, the rules engine can return a bunch of information like file mask, server name, ip address of deleiver server, etc.  You can thenuse this information to configure the dynamic send in the orchestration.  The real nice thing here is that you can update the rule set in the rules engine without redeploying the whole solution.  As a newb, these are some advanced concepts, but not as diificult as you may think.

For a simpler solution, you might want to look at setting the FILE Send adapters properties via it's Propery Schema (ie. File name, Directory, etc.).  You could pull these values from a database with a helper class inside an expresison shape.  On each message ogig out, use the property shcema to set where the message will be sent and named.  This way, you just update the database as things change.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using dynamic send ports to achieve this - if your subscribers are truly dynamic. This introduces a bit of complexity since you'll need to use an orchestration to configure the send port's properties based on your rules.

If you can, try and remove the complexity. If you know that you don't need to be truly dynamic when adding subscribers (i.e. a subscriber and it's rules can be configured one time only) and you have a manageable number of subscribers then I would suggest configuring each subscriber using it's own send port and use a filter to create subscriptions based on message context properties. The beauty of this approach is that you don't need to create and deploy an orchestration and this becomes a highly performant and scalable solution.